# Creating a cross-scope variable in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to create a variable that would change for all currently running php pages. For example I would like a string, that will change in any open page when I change it in one of the pages using type box. Is that possible to achieve with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with PHP alone.

You have a client that makes a request to a server, that resolves the request with PHP and send the client a respond, its stateless. You cannot tell the server to refresh all request from the other clients.

[image]

Its possible to read data from a webserver after the page has loaded with AJAX 
(Asynchronous JavaScript And XML).

If you would like to update a value on all other clients directly when another client is changing something, then you need a WebSocket.